# Desktop, side bar and top bar not responding

Tags: 20.04

All the panels and desktop had frozen on my session with Ubuntu 20.04. They didn't respond before I log out and log back in. Any idea why it would happen?

Comment: No idea at all. I do not think anyone can help with this meager information. What does `dmesg` say? You might also check your `.journalctl -xe` (don't copy it, just the part that is relevant - it is huge). If you find sth, add the text into your question

Comment: I am running Ubuntu from a usb flash disk because my hard drive doesn't boot up. That is probably why. It's dying.

Comment: I has happened again. Which part of dmesg I should check?

Comment: check if there is sth like "---trace cut here--" and the end of `journalctl -xe`

Comment: I ran this command but I couldn't see anything like that. I searched for this problem here but nobody asked about it. It's weird that is only happening on my computer.

Comment: I still couldn't find a solution for this problem and it happens time to time. It's happening when I'm watching streaming video with VLC Player.